# Find Sub string in SSRS and evaluate or replace

Tags: string, t-sql, if-statement, reporting-services, substring

In SSRS I have data field called `Event_dt` it returns as `Digital` followed by Month, then Year. It looks like this `Digital January 2021` or `Digital May 2019`

**Question 1:** In one field - I need to truncate the word `Digital` so the string would only read `January 2021` or `May 2019`

**Question 2:** In the second string i need to evaluate, if `Event_dt` string contains the word `Digital` then it should output something else. I know the iff(part ... but i'm not sure how to get the sub string part in SSRS.

Comment: Why not separate these on the query?  It would be much easier to work with if you had a field for just the first part of the string and the date separate.

Comment: I could separate them. But the problem is the second string is only in SSRS and the only way to evaluate it is if the first string has the word Digital in it. If we remove it we can't evaluate part two.

Comment: If they are separate, they should still come through in the same row.  Meaning you can just do `=IIF(Fields!FirstString.Value = "Digital", Fields!SomethingElse.Value, Fields!SecondString.Value)`.  If that's not how the data is laid out, I may be misunderstanding the issue.

Comment: The second string in SSRS is hardcoded text. Now they want logic that's evaluated based on event-dt field. It could be a regular date or not if the date is digital date (a marker in the code) then we want second string to change. We don't pass it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q1, replacing is fairly straight-forward. Use the REPLACE function and replace `Digital` with an empty string. Don't forget the space after `Digital`.

```
=Replace(Fields!Event_dt.Value, "Digital ", "")
```

For Q2, you don't say how you want to replace the text. To check if the field has a certain string, you can use the **InStr** function. It returns the starting position of the string to be found in the string. If it doesn't find the string in you field, it returns **0** (you check for 0 of not 0 if you just need to determine if it's there and not where).

```
=IIF(InStr(Fields!Event_dt.Value, "Digital") > 0, <Has String Part>, <ELSE Part>)
```

In SSRS, the MID function is the same as SUBSTRING - it returns the characters from the start point indicated in the first argument and the number of characters to return in the second argument.

You could actually write the REPLACE with this - though it would be more complicated.

```
=IIF(InStr(Fields!Event_dt.Value, "Digital") > 0, MID(Fields!Event_dt.Value, 9, LEN(Fields!Event_dt.Value)), Fields!Event_dt.Value)
```

This would read as

IF the EVENT DT contains Digital (i.e. value returned from INSTR is greater than 0), then return the EVENT DT field from character 9 through the end of the string, otherwise return the EVENT DT field.

Comment: for Q2, what I'm looking to do is say if the word digital exists write "this event is digital only" if it doesn't exist it should say "this event will be located at ... etc"